# Matomo not showing tag manager

Tags: matomo

I have matomo installed on Ec2 and I set up the connection.  And, I am getting regular user data, but do not see the menu for the tag manager. It sounds like this should be there by default, is there a way to get it to show?

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Matomo are you using? Make sure you use the latest version, which includes the Tag Manager plugin. Check under Administration > Plugins that the plugin is activated.